# JQuery function in Ajax call and dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling a page transition with ajax and I have a function which I want to use for this site. I was wondering if there is a way without the need to have the function both in the ajax call + dom.

It currently looks like this:

**DOM**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //(FUNCTION IN MY QUESTION)
        var divs = $(".row > .calenderItem");
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 3) {
        divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class='row calenderRow'></div>");
    }

});
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
        url:href,
        success: function(data){

            $(".pageChange").fadeOut(200,function(){

                var newPage = $(data).filter(".pageChange").html();
                $(".pageChange").html(newPage);
                $(".pageChange").fadeIn(600);

                //Row Maker (FUNCTION IN MY QUESTION)
                var divs = $(".row > .calenderItem");
                for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 3) {
                divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class='row calenderRow'></div>");
            }


            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: It's not a function now. Make it one. Extract the code from both places. Create and name the function and call it from both places.

Comment: @isherwood - in all fairness , what the OP posted in the first code block IS a function that even uses the `function()` semantics. Beyond that you suggestion is solid.

Comment: got it. That worked for me. Thanks :)